# Having error when vb.net application is used in different OS

Tags: .net, registry

A .net application is used at XP OS and everything is working fine until the OS is changed to Windows 7. At first have an error "Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {4E084A82-8FE7-11D0-9125-0004AC3617E1} failed due to the following error: 80040154". I checked the registry and the reg file is missing so i input the file.

But now had a new error again which is "System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80020009): Exception occurred. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80020009 (DISP_E_EXCEPTION))".

The application is to connect to an IBM peak system and run some Macros from there.

Please advise me on this as I have been digging in this for quite long already and giving me headache.

Comment: just adding the registry key for the COM component is obviously not going to fix the problem. you need to get a version of the COM component compatible with Windows 7 and register it using regsvr32 on the machine that will be running your app

Comment: Mike, please enlighten me more on the part of register it using regsvr32.

Comment: you need to try to debug the app to see which com component it is looking for. once you figure that out, you need to find the 64 bit (i'm assuming win7 64 bit) compatible library and install it on the machine. regsvr32 is a MS program to register COM components on the machine (COM components need to be able to register themself). if you aren't familiar with COM, much of this might not make sense... it might help if you read a high level COM overview online to give you an idea how the process generally works...

Answer (score 1):

You sure there was not some kind of pre-requisite install for this to run on the XP machine?  It looks like maybe the application has a reference for a COM iterop that does not exist on the Windows 7 machine.  I would recommend firing up Visual Studio and examining what references are included in the project.  Possibly you installed something to support the IBM peak system that deploys the necessary COM component.

Comment: The Peak System is working well at the new Windws 7 machine and other macros from excel files also. I have checked the dll files also.

Answer (score 0):

Is your application compiling as 'Any CPU'? It's a possibility that your Windows 7 64bit and your XP is running 32bit, which can cause havoc with COM objects.